# Should application config be committed to source control?

Tags: git, config, commit

When I say application config, I don't mean secrets. We all know secrets shouldn't be committed. But what about config like number of workers, throttling, etc.? Should those be committed into source control or kept out?

I work at a startup where I've heard that changing app config is the same as changing app code, so it should be committed. What is standard practice in the industry? If it isn't standard practice, it this something that only makes sense in startups?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but probably worth taking a look at https://12factor.net/.

Comment: I do know of 12 factor app. I'm just curious what the industry standard is on config. Is there a difference between secrets and other config? Or a difference between config used in small-scale and large-scale apps

Answer (score 0):

I think this is really dependent on the project, team, and how flexible you want your configuration to be.

There's not going to be any one specific answer; but I would say: Set sensible defaults on all of your application configuration, but then allow for them to be adjusted downstream.

Something along the lines of:

```
workers: ENV['worker_count'] || 5
```

Would make perfect sense if this is something you want to be configurable; but if you know for a fact that it only ever makes sense to have `X` for `configuration_value_of_choice` then it may make sense to keep that locked in.